# Change ids and names for cloned elements

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a form where I allow the user to enter multiple delegate details.Here is the snippet of the html page.

```
<div id="Delegate1" class="clonedInput">
                    <h4 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Delegate #1</h4>
                    <div class="w-row">
                        <div class="column-5 w-col w-col-6"><label for="email-5">*First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="first_name" data-name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" required=""></div>
                        <div class="column-4 w-col w-col-6"><label for="email-5">*Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="last_name" data-name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" id="last_name" required=""></div>
                    </div><label for="email-5">*Job Title / Position</label>
                    <select id="title" name="title" class="w-select">
                        <option value="">What best describes your role?</option>
                        <option value="Partner/Principal">Partner/Principal</option>
                        <option value="Director/CEO/CFO">Director/CEO/CFO</option>
                        <option value="General Manager">General Manager</option>
                        <option value="Senior Manager">Senior Manager</option>
                        <option value="Manager">Manager</option>

   </select>
                    <div class="w-row">
                        <div class="column-10 w-col w-col-6"><label for="email-5">*Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="email_address" data-name="email_address" placeholder="Email Address" id="email_address" required=""></div>
                        <div class="column-11 w-col w-col-6"><label for="email-5">Mobile</label>
                            <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="mobile" data-name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" id="mobile"></div>
                    </div>
                    <label for="email-5">*Postal Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="mailing_street" data-name="mailing_street" placeholder="Postal Address" id="mailing_street" required="">
                    <div class="w-row">
                        <div class="column w-col w-col-4"><label for="Suburb">*Suburb</label>
                            <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="mailing_suburb" data-name="mailing_suburb" placeholder="Enter your email" id="mailing_suburb" required=""></div>
                        <div class="column-2 w-col w-col-4"><label for="email-5">*State</label>
                            <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="mailing_state" data-name="mailing_state" placeholder="State" id="mailing_state" required=""></div>
                        <div class="column-3 w-col w-col-4"><label for="email-5">*Postcode</label>
                            <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="mailing_postcode" data-name="mailing_postcode" placeholder="Postcode" id="mailing_postcode" required=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <label for="email-5">Please note any special requirements (eg. dietary, mobility, hearing or sight)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="message" data-name="message" placeholder="Special Requirements" id="message">
                </div>
                <div class="w-row">
                    <div class="column-6 w-col w-col-6"><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="delegate-button w-button">Add New Delegate</button></div>
                    <div class="column-7 w-col w-col-6"><button type="button" id="btnDel" class="delegate-button remove w-button">Remove Above Delegate</button></div>
                </div>
```

Now when I click on addbtn, it will clone a new set of delegate fields and I have to change the cloned elements' id and name to a certain format for my back end to process the form.I am using jquery to do this.

```
$(function() {
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length,
        newNum = new Number(num + 1),
        newElem = $('#Delegate' + num).clone().attr('id', 'Delegate' + newNum).fadeIn('slow');
    newElem.find('.heading-reference').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').html('Delegate #' + newNum);
    newElem.find('.w-select').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_title').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_title').val('');
    newElem.find('.w-input').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_first_name').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_first_name').val('');
    newElem.find('.w-input').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_last_name').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_last_name').val('');
    newElem.find('.w-input').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_email_address').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_email_address').val('');
    newElem.find('.w-input').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_mobile').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_mobile').val('');
    newElem.find('.w-input').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_message').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_message').val('');
    $('#Delegate' + num).after(newElem);
    $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);
    if (newNum == 5)
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
    $('#number_of_delegate').val(newNum);
});
```

I am able to change the attributes of heading-reference successfully but I am unable to pick up the input field attributes as they belong to the same class 'w-input'. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I am interested in your problem, but I don't understand what you are asking.  Can you explain what you mean by "unable to pick up the input field attributes"?

Comment: okay. Lets take heading-reference for example, in delegate #2 , the id is set to ID2_reference and its the same with name. but when I try to change the id and name of input fields, it does not happen.

Comment: why you need all element have an id?

Comment: Even if I use .find(#first_name), it does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are targeting `.w-input`, and their are multiple elements with that class, you are targeting all elements with that class.  If you were to `console.log('newElem.find('.w-input'))`, you would receive an array.  By iterating through each element, you can target them individually, use regex test for a digit in the string, and replace accordingly.

#### Solution:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
      var num = $('.clonedInput').length,
        newNum = new Number(num + 1),
        newElem = $('#Delegate' + num).clone().attr('id', 'Delegate' + newNum).fadeIn('slow');

      newElem.find('.heading-reference').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').html('Delegate #' + newNum);
      newElem.find('.w-select').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_title').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_title').val('');

      //loop through each element
      newElem.find('.w-input').each(function(el) {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        var uniqueId; //hold a var for the unique id
        if(/(\d+)/.test(currentId)) {  //if digits exist
          uniqueId = currentId.replace(/(\d+)/, newNum);  //replace digits with the new number
        } else {
          uniqueId = 'ID' + newNum + '_' + currentId; //otherwise, replace with current id plus number etc.
        }
        $(this).attr('id', uniqueId).attr('name', uniqueId).val('');  //the the name and id to the new unique id
      });


      $('#Delegate' + num).after(newElem);
      $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();
      $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);
      if (newNum == 5)
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
      $('#number_of_delegate').val(newNum);
    });
```

#### Snippet

```js
$(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
      var num = $('.clonedInput').length,
        newNum = new Number(num + 1),
        newElem = $('#Delegate' + num).clone().attr('id', 'Delegate' + newNum).fadeIn('slow');

      newElem.find('.heading-reference').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').html('Delegate #' + newNum);
      newElem.find('.w-select').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_title').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_title').val('');

      newElem.find('.w-input').each(function(el) {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        var uniqueId;
        if(/(\d+)/.test(currentId)) {
          uniqueId = currentId.replace(/(\d+)/, newNum);
        } else {
          uniqueId = 'ID' + newNum + '_' + currentId;
        }
        $(this).attr('id', uniqueId).attr('name', uniqueId).val('');
      });


      $('#Delegate' + num).after(newElem);
      $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();
      $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);
      if (newNum == 5)
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
      $('#number_of_delegate').val(newNum);
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Delegate1" class="clonedInput">
 <h4 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Delegate #1</h4>
 <div class="w-row">
  <div class="column-5 w-col w-col-6"><label for="email-5">*First Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="first_name" data-name="first_name"
          placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" required=""></div>
  <div class="column-4 w-col w-col-6"><label for="email-5">*Last Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="last_name" data-name="last_name"
          placeholder="Last Name" id="last_name" required=""></div>
 </div>
 <label for="email-5">*Job Title / Position</label>
 <select id="title" name="title" class="w-select">
  <option value="">What best describes your role?</option>
  <option value="Partner/Principal">Partner/Principal</option>
  <option value="Director/CEO/CFO">Director/CEO/CFO</option>
  <option value="General Manager">General Manager</option>
  <option value="Senior Manager">Senior Manager</option>
  <option value="Manager">Manager</option>

 </select>
 <div class="w-row">
  <div class="column-10 w-col w-col-6"><label for="email-5">*Email Address</label>
   <input type="email" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="email_address" data-name="email_address"
          placeholder="Email Address" id="email_address" required=""></div>
  <div class="column-11 w-col w-col-6"><label for="email-5">Mobile</label>
   <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="mobile" data-name="mobile"
          placeholder="Mobile Number" id="mobile"></div>
 </div>
 <label for="email-5">*Postal Address</label>
 <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="mailing_street" data-name="mailing_street"
        placeholder="Postal Address" id="mailing_street" required="">
 <div class="w-row">
  <div class="column w-col w-col-4"><label for="Suburb">*Suburb</label>
   <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="mailing_suburb" data-name="mailing_suburb"
          placeholder="Enter your email" id="mailing_suburb" required=""></div>
  <div class="column-2 w-col w-col-4"><label for="email-5">*State</label>
   <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="mailing_state" data-name="mailing_state"
          placeholder="State" id="mailing_state" required=""></div>
  <div class="column-3 w-col w-col-4"><label for="email-5">*Postcode</label>
   <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="mailing_postcode" data-name="mailing_postcode"
          placeholder="Postcode" id="mailing_postcode" required=""></div>
 </div>
 <label for="email-5">Please note any special requirements (eg. dietary, mobility, hearing or sight)</label>
 <input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="message" data-name="message"
        placeholder="Special Requirements" id="message">
</div>
<div class="w-row">
 <div class="column-6 w-col w-col-6">
  <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="delegate-button w-button">Add New Delegate</button>
 </div>
 <div class="column-7 w-col w-col-6">
  <button type="button" id="btnDel" class="delegate-button remove w-button">Remove Above Delegate</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand what's going wrong. Does your code work? I cannot see any changes

Comment: I have input elements with the same class w-input other than the delegate division I posted. You think that would affect the results? Still ID and name is not getting updated

Comment: That depends on if they are nested withing the `Delegate` ids or not.  I can't confirm with out seeing the code.  Are you saying the ID and name is not getting updated in your own code?  It is getting updated in the snippet I have posted.